# preventing juno-atom from recloning all julia packages

Tags: julia, package, atom-editor, juno-ide

I am new to both julia and atom and trying to set them both up together. I installed juno for atom and am trying to run a julia script. I relocated my package directory for Julia from ~, because at my workplace there is a limit on space in said directory.

how do I make atom recognize the packages are in a different directory?

I am currently working on a CENTOS machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find your .juliarc.jl file, and insert the line

```
ENV["JULIA_PKGDIR"] = # your package directory
```

BTW this issue is unrelated to Atom. It is the julia installation that keeps track of the package directory.

Comment: it kind of is if you set a JULIA_PKGDIR variable in the shell configuration file. In this case, the problem happens within julia, but not when calling julia from the commandline. Still, this fixes it.

Comment: Well, fair point. I think it is generally recommended to use the .juliarc.jl file, though.